# Dictionary from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dictionary

I read two columns of a  large file (10 million lines) using pandas read_csv (first line is the header), and now I want to convert the dataframe to a dictionary where the 1st column is the key and the second column is the value.

```
col_name = ['A', 'B']; 
df = pd.read_csv(f_loc, usecols = col_name, sep = "\s+", dtype={'B':np.float16});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `index` with first `column` by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and convert by [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['A', 'B'])
print (df)
   a  b
0  1  2
1  3  4

df = df.set_index('A')['B'].to_dict()
print (df)
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Another idea with `zip`:

```
d = dict(zip(df['A'], df['B']))
print (d)
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```

Or:

```
d = dict(df.values)
print (d)
{1: 2, 3: 4}
```